# ATMEGA32U4-AU Schematics Sanity Check

Tags: schematics, review, atmega32u4

I had previously asked [a few questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/679461/atmega32u2-schematics-sanity-check) about ATMEGA32U2 and got great feedback. I updated my schematics and went ahead to order, only to realize that JLCPCB is currently out of ATMEGA32U2. I have replaced it with an ATMEGA32U4-AU, but since my background is software development, I might have made mistakes and would like some feedback on the updated schematics.

[image: Schematics]

U1~U6 are independent boards which come with their own circuitry for power line noise filtering.

I have placed C6~C11 as close possible to U7 on the PCB, while C5 is a little farther away.

The board is powered independently.

Can anyone point out any possible mistakes my schematics might have?

Comment: So how did you change the circuit, when you made changes from one chip to another?

Comment: @Justme VBUS and VCC are isolated. Added 100nF capacitors to for every VCC pad on MCU.

Comment: Why receive only?  No transmit.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Not really. These LCDs don't send anything. They just receive and show readings.